# finding the derivative of ${{\sqrt x}(x^2 - {\sqrt x})}$

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to find the derivative of this expression

${{\sqrt x}(x^2 - {\sqrt x})}$

I would first of simplify the expression to:

${x^{1\over2}(x^2 - x^{1\over2})}$

And then apply ${x^{1\over2}}$ to the term in the brackets"

=> ${x^{3 \over2} - x}$

Then to find the derivative of this expression I get

${{3\over2} x^{1\over2} -1}$

${{3\over2} {\sqrt x} -1}$

But the answer in the book is:

${{5 \over 2}\sqrt[3]{x} - 1}$

Comment: The answer in the book is $\frac52x^{\frac32}-1=\frac52x\sqrt{x}-1$ because $x^{\frac12}x^2=x^{\frac52}$, not $x^{\frac32}$.

Comment: Your first product is wrong:$x^{\frac{1}{2}}x^2=x^{\frac{5}{2}}$

Comment: You distributed incorrectly. What's $2+\frac12$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, your mistake $\sqrt x\cdot x^2\ne x^{3/2}$,  $$\sqrt x(x^2-\sqrt x)=x^{1/2}(x^2-x^{1/2})=x^{5/2}-x$$
hence, $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^{5/2}-x)=\frac 52x^{\frac 52-1}-1=\color{red}{\frac 52x^{\frac 32}-1}$$